# how can I configure Jenkins to use maven that's pre-installed on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins

I have installed Eclipse Neon, it comes with maven pre-built in it. While configuring jenkins, I would need to set values for Maven_HOME. Since I have maven integrated with eclipse, I am not sure where to find the maven installation path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embedded Maven Runtime of m2e is located in the `org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_<version>` folder in the plugins folder of your eclipse installation. Yet it is unusable for using it as a local maven installation under Jenkins as it does not contain the expected folder structure.

A better solution would be to let Jenkins install a Maven Runtime for you as shown below in the Global Tools section of the Jenkins configuration.

[image: Maven Runtime Installation]

Comment: I have installed a standalone maven onto my computer and configured it on Jenkins as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Simply untick the Install Automatically option to manually define the MAVEN_HOME environment variable to point to the custom location

[image]